# Isn't double able to represent any 2^n number without precision issues? n is natural

Tags: c#, double, double-precision

This code:

```
double x = 2.0;
for(int i = 1 ; i<1024 ; i+=i) {
    Console.WriteLine( String.Format( "2^{0} = {1:F0}", i, x ) );
    x*=x;
}
```

Outputs:

```
2^1 = 2
2^2 = 4
2^4 = 16
2^8 = 256
2^16 = 65536
2^32 = 4294967296
2^64 = 18446744073709600000
2^128 = 340282366920938000000000000000000000000
2^256 = 115792089237316000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
2^512 = 13407807929942600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

I thought that double's formula is `sign * 2 ^ exponent * fraction`; To Illustrate my situation; With setting the `fraction` to `0.5`, the sign to positive, and by setting `exponent` to any value between `-1024` to `1023`, I can present any `2^n` number that is in the `exponent`'s range; What is wrong with this deduction? Is the formula incomplete?

Comment: You should probably edit the question to restrict the range of exponents.

Comment: @leppie ? To what exactly?

Comment: To the question in the subject ;p Hint: Decompose the binary form of a double, then do the math.

Comment: @leppie You are ~70K user, there's body to the post except the title; try reading it. :D

Comment: That issue is addressed below ;p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `double` *can* represent powers of 2 exactly, as demonstrated by the following code (which uses Jon Skeet's [`DoubleConverter`](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx) class):

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("2^{0} = {1}", i, DoubleConverter.ToExactString(x)));
```

For the F0 specifier, why did the .NET designers choose to round the value off after the 15 most significant decimal digits?

My guess: Displaying the exact value (such as 18446744073709551616) might imply that the `double` is *precise* to all those digits, when in fact a `double` cannot distinguish between that value and 18446744073709600000. Also, displaying a rounded value is consistent with exponential notation: 1.84467440737096E+19.

Comment: I think this is formatting problem, I just tested it in C++ with `printf` (`printf("%.0lf",...);` and it works.

Comment: It is hard to believe that the inexact digits are just set to zero. Why would that be the case if it is instead possible to format the value exactly?

Comment: This appears to be a correct answer to a different question.

Comment: @BenVoigt Why is this? The problem lies in the formatting implemention and not in the double's definition. I won't accept and wait.

Comment: Is there evidence that this answer is correct? At the moment it is just a guess.

Comment: @usr I tested it in C++ and it works. I just don't know how to fix it in C#.

Comment: @usr: It's possible to write a conversion routine that displays the *exact* value of a double. However, the exact value would typically be meaningless because it would imply precision that a double doesn't have. Therefore, .NET just rounds the value off when formatting it.

Comment: That sounds like a choice with purely bad effects. This formatting lessens precision and introduces a bias. Surprising, if true. It is still not proven. The C++ test does not prove it because C++ might just be calculating "more correctly" than C# does it. Indistinguishable at the moment.

Comment: @LyingOnTheSky: Because your question asks about `double`, not about `String.Format`.  Michael has answered the question you failed to ask, namely "Why does string.Format return incorrect least significant digits when presented with inputs that are exactly represented?"

Comment: @BenVoigt My question is obsolete, because my initial assumption was that `double` is the problem, and not that `String.Format` is the one that made `double` look bad. I am agreeing with your point, but if I will act on it then I will just open new question and close this one.

Answer (score 0):

No.  Your argument fails at "by setting exponent to any value".

There's a limited range on `exponent`, you cannot represent

```
pow(2, 1000000)
```

even though 1000000 is a natural number.

Comment: But why it can't handle `2^512`? This is the question. Is it unclear?

Comment: Actually 512 is in the range, there's 2048 possibilities to the `exponent` value. That is from -1024 to 1023.

Comment: Shouldn't 2^64 be representable? The exponents surely can take the value 64.

Comment: ok, sorry, 1023 is the edge, not 511.  There are slightly fewer than 2048 allowed values because of non-finite numbers and denormals (-1024 isn't allowed either)

Comment: @usr: `2^64` is `62`.  `pow(2, 64)` is representable, what makes you think it's not.

Comment: @BenVoigt If it can't represent number because it's out of it's `exponent`'s range, it will just print `Infinity`, just try it. (Change `<1024` to `<=1024` for example)

Comment: Well, the examples in the question suggest that it is not representable. Or, it is a formatting issue.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9.aspx

The double keyword signifies a simple type that stores 64-bit floating-point values. The following table shows the precision and approximate range for the double type.

```
Type
double

Approximate range
±5.0 × 10−324 to ±1.7 × 10308

Precision
15-16 digits
```

Answer (score 0):

That answer to your question is that an IEEE 754 double precision number is a 64-bit value:

- 1 bit is the sign
- 11 bits represent the exponent
- 52 bits represent the significand (but due to a little deep magick, the signficand actually has 53 bits of precision).

It can represent no more than 2<sup>64</sup> **discrete** values — the same as a 64-bit integer (and actually less due to things like `NaN`, positive and negative zero, etc.)

Its *range*, however, is much larger than that of a 64-bit integer: it can represent decimal values roughly from 10<sup>-308</sup> to 10<sup>+308</sup> ... albeit with with no more than 15 to 17 decimal digits of precision.

Floating point trades *precision* for *range*. It's a tradeoff.

See  [IEEE-754 Double Precision Binary Floating Point Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_double-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary64) for rather more details.

Even better, read David Goldberg's 1991 paper, ["What every computer scientist should know about floating-point arithmetic"](https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~dwharder/NumericalAnalysis/02Numerics/Double/paper.pdf):

> **Abstract.** Floating-point arithmetic is considered as esoteric subject by many people.
>   This is rather surprising, because floating-point is ubiquitous in computer systems:
>   Almost every language has a floating-point datatype; computers from PCs to supercomputers
>   have floating-point accelerators; most compilers will be called upon to compile floating-point
>   algorithms from time to time; and virtually every operating system must respond to floating-point
>   exceptions such as overflow. This paper presents a tutorial on the aspects of floating-point that
>   have a direct impact on designers of computer systems. It begins with background on floating-point
>   representation and rounding error, continues with a discussion of the IEEE floating point standard,
>   and concludes with examples of how computer system builders can better support floating point.
>
> David Goldberg. 1991. "What every computer scientist should know about floating-point arithmetic".
>   ACM Comput. Surv. 23, 1 (March 1991), 5-48. DOI=10.1145/103162.103163
>   http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/103162.103163